# Why using A record for OpenShift is bad idea?

Tags: dns, openshift

If I ping my OpenShift application I see some IP like this

**ec2-11-22-33-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com [11.22.33.44]**

Can I be sure that my IP is 11.22.33.44 and I can use it for A record in DNS settings?

In which cases this IP is changed ?

Never seen this inforamtion. All articles claim that only CNAME may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use an A record to point to your OpenShift application with an external domain.  That IP address can change at any time for outage or maintenance reasons.  You should always use a CNAME to point your domain name to your application url of the format app-domain.rhcloud.com

Answer (score -1):

Just found an answer.
This was not just my own IP.
Several sites have this IP too.
http://www.bing.com/search?q=IP:11.22.33.44